# py2exe compiling error : invalid syntax (_socket3.py, line 183)

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe

i am trying to compile a python application in single exe.
i am using python 2.7 and py2exe.

modules used in my application

- PyQt4
- Pymongo
- Psutil

when i start compiling i am getting following error :

```
*** searching for required modules ***
error: compiling 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gevent\_socket3.py' failed
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax (_socket3.py, line 183)
```

please tell me how to fix this error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Version 1.1.1 of gevent contains file *_socket3.py* that is for python 3. With a python 2.7 compatible py2exe compiling *_socket3.py* to *_socket3.pyc* will fail.

gevent package should probably be fixed so that it does not install _socket3.py file for python 2.7

As a workaround that file *C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gevent_socket3.py* can be removed. Also `options = {'py2exe': {'exclude': 'gevent._socket3'}}` for `setup()` might work.

Comment: Note that the py2exe parameter is `'excludes'` rather than `'exclude'`. See http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ListOfOptions for more info.